# Pygame.transform.rotate causes fatal pygame error

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, pygame

I'm trying to make a game using python and pygame, but need to use pygame.transform.rotate. As I call it following Error message occurs: (`c:/Users/foxcirc/Desktop/rxry` is the project path)

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Thread 0x00002890 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 296 in wait
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_io.py", line 40 in read
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_transport.py", line 27 in read_request
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_transport.py", line 215 in read
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\buffered\__init__.py", line 39 in _read
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\__init__.py", line 14 in readall
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\__init__.py", line 32 in read
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\protocol\binary.py", line 164 in read_message_begin
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\protocol\binary.py", line 372 in read_message_begin
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 212 in process_in
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 257 in process
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_server.py", line 34 in handle
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap
Thread 0x00002e58 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_io.py", line 110 in readall
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_transport.py", line 45 in _read_frame
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_transport.py", line 37 in _read_and_dispatch_next_frame
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_transport.py", line 64 in _read_forever
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap
Current thread 0x00002964 (most recent call first):
  File "<string>", line 9 in __init__
  File "C:/Users/foxcirc/Desktop/rxry/game/scripts/main.py", line 132 in <module>
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18 in execfile
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197 in runfile
  File "<input>", line 1 in <module>
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\code.py", line 90 in runcode
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\code.py", line 74 in runsource
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_types.py", line 35 in run
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 84 in do_add_exec
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_code_executor.py", line 106 in add_exec
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 258 in process_exec_queue
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 411 in start_client
  File "C:\Users\foxcirc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 483 in <module>
```

Here are all my imports, if that's important:

```
import pygame
from pickle import load as pickload
from os import chdir, walk; chdir(gamedir); del chdir
from sys import path; path.extend(gamedir); del path
```

I have tried to not importing pickle but nothing changed.
Also I've tried to call the function from another "part" of the program.

Here is how I use pygame.tranform.rotate:
**pygame.transform.rotate(self.bsurface, 10)**

*Using python 3.7 (32-bit) and pygame version 1.9.6.*

Comment: It is not much help but try updating to pygame 2.0.0.dev6 or newer. Sometimes it resolves issues like this one

Comment: How can I get this version of pygame? From github?

Comment: open cmd/powershell as admin and type `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6`

Comment: I installed the version, but it does not fix the issue, moreover the performance dropst But thanks anyway.

Comment: How do you use `pygame.transform.rotate`? Very likely, this is a bug in your application caused by the ill use of `pygame.transform.rotate`. I am voting to close this question as there is no [**Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've added an example at the bottom of the question, I can add more if you want, but It's a bit difficult since my code is split over multiple files and classes.

Comment: So now I've found the issue. I see how bad I wrote this question. Every importand detail is missing. I've addet the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several things and now I found the error!

It turns out, that the surface I used in the function initialy had a width and a length of **0**.
Calling the *pygame.transform.rotate* function on a surface with a width and / or height of **0** apparently doesn not result in a fancy *"You can't call this with a surface wich has a width of 0"* message. You just get a segfault.